# How to localise the title for CreditCard Component in Adyen?

Tags: ios, adyen

How to localise the big title "Credit Card" at top?

Here we are in Russian, and I localised all the little fields titles. You just have to overwrite something like `adyen.card.numberItem.title`. But none are defined for the big title. So it will always be in English. Customers is complaining and he is right. Any idea someone?

I'm using a `CardComponent`.

[image: CC CardComponent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to support [Localization](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/ios/components#localization) is to define `shopperLocale` where `ru_RU` is already supported (you shouldn't need then to override every field - however you can still do that if you prefer).

The payment name can be localized setting `paymentMethodObject.name`, after fetching the response from the payment methods request.

Comment: Setting `shopperLocale` to `ru` do the trick. Thanks. In the app I just know if I'm `ru` or `de` but not what country I'm in, so I can't use `lang-COUNTRY` full ISO 639-1 code. But apparently Adyen is smart enough 